# How to set different images on ImageView's enabled/disabled programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've a requirement in which an `ImageView`'s enabled state is changed.
I have 2 images: one for the enabled state & another for the disabled state.

**Without using a selector**, how can I change the `Image src` when the `setEnabled(true/false)` is changed?

That is:

```
imageView.setEnabled(true);
imageView - use image imgEnabled.png

imageView.setEnabled(false);
imageView - use image imgDisabled.png
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 if(imageView.isEnabled())
{
 imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgEnabled);
}
else
{
 imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgDisabled);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the image yourself using setImageResource.
But this may not be appropriate, since your view's state may be changed from your code anywhere.

```
imageView.setEnabled(true);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgEnabled);

imageView.setEnabled(false);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imgDisabled);
```

You can also write your own class that extends ImageView
and override the following method

```
@Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {

        super.drawableStateChanged();

        if(isEnabled())
        {
            //set drawable for enabled state here
        }
        else
        {
            //set drawable for disabled state here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to change image resource-

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```